# Getting Error Whie parsing JSON in .NET

Tags: .net, json

I'm trying to parse the following Json string

```
{
{
"data": [
  {
    "uid": 100001648098091,
    "first_name": "Payal",
    "last_name": "Sinha",
    "sex": "female",
    "pic_big_with_logo": "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/external.ak/safe_image.php?d=AQAi8VLrTMB-UUEs&bust=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhprofile-ash2%2Fv%2Ft1.0-1%2Fs200x200%2F10018_433988026666130_85247169_n.jpg%3Foh%3Dc2774db94dff4dc9f393070c9715ef65%26oe%3D552CF366&logo&v=5&w=200&h=150",
    "username": "payal.sinha.505"
  }
]
}
}
```

I've tried following code

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                dynamic result = fb.Get("fql",
                            new { q = "SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, sex, pic_big_with_logo, username FROM user WHERE uid=me()" });

        dynamic dynamicJsonResult = JObject.Parse(result);
        var userDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FacebookUserDetailAPIResponseWrapper>>(dynamicJsonResult.data);
```

class

```
public class FacebookUserDetails
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    //Password = EncryptionClass.Md5Hash(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),                        
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public string pic_big_with_log { get; set; } 
}
```

[image]
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong But the same approach i use to parse every json string.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Possibly because you don't have a mapping for `uid` on your POCO?

Comment: Have you define `FacebookUserDetailAPIResponseWrapper` class?

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you really have two open brackets and two close brackets in your JSON string? I don't think that's valid JSON.

Comment: @StuartLC mapping uid is not compulsory i guess to retrieve all other information

Comment: @Avijit that was a typo mistake, though I changed it to class FacebookUserDetails, but it is still not working

Comment: @zerodiff , yes it is having two brackets in JSON, that's why I'm confused how to parse this. I've attached snapshot of the same.

Comment: Look at these links if that helps http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-making-requests  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584105/facebook-sdk-c-sharp-get-friends-list

Comment: The title says that you're getting an error but you haven't actually told us what the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var jsonString = @"{
                              ""data"": [
                                  {
                                    ""uid"": ""100001648098091"",
                                    ""first_name"": ""Payal"",
                                    ""last_name"": ""Sinha"",
                                    ""sex"": ""female"",
                                    ""pic_big_with_logo"": ""https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/external.ak/safe_image.php?d=AQAi8VLrTMB-UUEs&bust=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhprofile-ash2%2Fv%2Ft1.0-1%2Fs200x200%2F10018_433988026666130_85247169_n.jpg%3Foh%3Dc2774db94dff4dc9f393070c9715ef65%26oe%3D552CF366&logo&v=5&w=200&h=150"",
                                    ""username"": ""payal.sinha.505"",
                                  },
                                ]
                              }";
        dynamic userinfo = JValue.Parse(jsonString);



        foreach (dynamic userin userinfo.data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + user.uid);
        }

        IList<FacebookUserDetails> userDeatils = new List<FacebookUserDetails>();

        foreach (dynamic userinfoItr in userinfo.data)
        {
            FacebookUserDetails userdetail= userinfoItr.ToObject<FacebookUserDetails>();
            userDeatils.Add(userdetail);
        }
```