# Getting empty list of friends

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get facebook user's friends list using the below code and `user_friends,read_friendlists` permissions but it does return zero friends.

```
var accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
                    //MessageBox.Show("token = " + accesstoken);
                    var client = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
                    dynamic myInfo = client.Get("/me/friends");
                    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

                    buffer.AppendLine();
                    foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo.data)
                    {
                        buffer.Append(friend.id);
                        buffer.Append(" = ");
                        buffer.Append(friend.name);
                        buffer.AppendLine();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("friends = " + buffer.ToString());
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting response in myInfo?

Comment: You mean, if request is valid, ie, run without error? if so, yes. It's only empty.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584105/facebook-sdk-c-sharp-get-friends-list

Comment: @WizKid: How does this app works then? https://apps.facebook.com/friendlistexporter

Comment: Did you even read the post I linked to? In API v1.0 you can get all friends. In API v2.0 and later you can't

Comment: I quickly read, sorry. But can I still get the Facebook C# SDK with API 1.0 around? I can't find it on official web site

Comment: If you don't have an v1.0 app you can't use it. And, v1.0 will only work until April 30th, 2015.